# Как опустить ссылки в подвале сайта

Tags: html, css

Делаю футер для сайта и не могу опустить ссылки посередине до самого низа

[image: подвал сайта]

```css
.footer {
  background: #194569;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.footer-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-copyright p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.footer-butt {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 3;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  background-color: #194569;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 30rem;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 187px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-butt2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 195px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-icons p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.footer-icons-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-icons-row > * + * {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.footer-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-row">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        <p>Есть вопрос?</p>
        <p>Задайте его нам</p>
        <div class="footer-butt">
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Вопрос">
          </form>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="footer-butt2">Почта</div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-contacts">
        <a href="1list.html" class="footer-button">Главная</a>
        <a href="2list.html" class="footer-button">Туры</a>
        <a href="3list.html" class="footer-button">Отзывы</a>
        <a href="4list.html" class="footer-button">Акции</a>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-icons">
        <p>Обратная связь</p>
        <p>+7 (930) 074-63-28</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>+7 (956) 632-85-48</p>
        <p>Мы в соц. сетях</p>

        <div class="footer-icons-row">
          <a href="#"><img src="./social/vk.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="./social/tg.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="./social/inst.svg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте объект footer-contacts в стилях и задайте ему нижнее положение. Как я понял, вы задали нижнее положения для класса "footer-button"